# Retrieve list of columns in Excel table on a specific worksheet with ImportExcel Powershell module

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a specific brief: retrieve the column names of an Excel table that is on a given worksheet, using the [ImportExcel Powershell module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).

Is this possible or am I just better off reading the workbook with an OLE-DB connection or something similar?

I have tried to utilize ImportExcel's GetExcelTable command but Powershell doesn't seem to recognize it - this was my vain attempt to get a reference of the table and somehow use it to get to the column names.

Here's the code snippet:

```
$table = GetExcelTable -FilePath $xlsxConfigFilePath -SheetName "SYS_SourceSystem"
```

And here is the error I get when I try to run it ($xlsxConfigFilePath is set as a valid path to the Excel workbook):

> GetExcelTable : The term 'GetExcelTable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>    name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:9 char:10
>   + $table = GetExcelTable -FilePath $xlsxConfigFilePath -SheetName "SYS_ ...
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GetExcelTable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `GetExcelTable` isn't a command from that module. I think you are looking for the `Import-Excel` function. e.g. `$table = Import-Excel -Path $xlsxConfigFilePath -WorksheetName "SYS_SourceSystem"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @BenH's suggestion I figured out a solution that uses the ImportExcel module without the need of an OLE-DB connection.

First, we get a reference of the table (the worksheet only contains one table):

```
$table = Import-Excel -Path $xlsxConfigFilePath -WorksheetName "SYS_SourceSystem"
```

Since the `$table` variable we get from this is a PSCustomObject, we can parse it with the `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
$table | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | %{
"$($_.Name)"
}
```

We use the NoteProperty to refer to the part of the object that holds the column names.

Here is the output with the column names:

```
ID
SRCS_Code
SRCS_Name
SRS_Platform
SSIS_ConnectionName
```

Thanks everyone for the help!